# Send data from watchKit to iPhone and got callback without launching iOS App

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to send a dictionary from WatchKit to iPhone in watchOS 2 and get a reply(callback) from iPhone without launching iPhone app.

In watchOS 1, this is possible by calling openParentApplication method when button tapped in Watch:

```
@IBAction func btnTapped() {
        let dictionary = ["Button":0]

        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dictionary, reply: { (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
            print(replyInfo["ReturnButton"])
        })
    }
```

and in AppDelegate class:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
    int key = (int)[[userInfo objectForKey:@"Button"] integerValue];

    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    switch (key){
    case 0:
        [dict setObject:@"Button1" forKey:@"ReturnButton"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    reply(dict);
}
```

Its goes in handler and print "Button1" without launching iOS app.I don't know this is possible or not for watchOS 2.

Comment: The "openParentApplication" is opening the parent app in background, it isnt actually launching it.

Comment: Yup!! i know that, "openParentApplication" is opening the parent app in background and send callback in watch without launching iPhone app, actual this is same thing i want it in watch OS2

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in watchOS 2. They have deprecated the openParent call and replaced it with a new connectivity framework. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH6-SW1) in the watchOS 2 transition guide states:

> The framework provides options for transferring data in the background
>   or while both apps are active and replaces the existing
>   openParentApplication:reply: method of the WKInterfaceController
>   class.

[Connectivity Framework Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015269)

The function you should look into is

```
func transferUserInfo(_ userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) -> WCSessionUserInfoTransfer
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me right now. iPhone never receives the userinfo (while it receives other events like didReceiveMessage, etc.. so this is not a delegate error)